# How do I pass a Jquery variable to php variables for the Select Query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).load(function(){
   $("body").click(function(){

        var s = window.getSelection();
        s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
        var b = s.toString();

        s.modify('extend','forward','word');
        var a = s.toString();
        s.modify('move','forward','character');

        var variablej=b+a; //variablej is Jquery Variable

       //how to pass a Jquery variable to php variable
      <?php   $variablephp = "<script>document.write(variablej)</script>"   ?> //variablephp is php variable

<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM translate where English='$variablephp'"); ?>

</script>
```

Comment: You can do that via `ajax`

Comment: how can i . I cant now. plz lett made an easily example?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a scripting language to generate output as HTML for example. Once generated by PHP, PHP ends its execution and Apache, Nginx or another server sends the response to the browser.

You cannot send a value from Javascript context to PHP, because its executed on serve side, and Javascript is executed on Client side.

You can ask for another request, just to return the needed value or selection , an Ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "/you-server-url-for-retrieve-data-from-select",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {"variablej": variablej},
    "success": function(data) {
        $("#list-container").html(data);
    }
});
```

You will receive the value on POST data as variablej

Comment: On you action you can access the value as $_POST["variablej"], then you can execute your PHP code : mysql_query("SELECT * FROM translate where English='$_POST["variablej"]'");...